# Creating filtered Table to remove #N/A in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, excel-2010, openpyxl

I am wanting to create a filtered table to remove #N/A from my table.  This can be achieved easily in vba by setting columns 9 to between values of -100 and 100 which should automatically remove #N/A and make the table look like the ideal table.  Though I am wanting to do this with python any idea on how this can be achieved?

[image]

Current attempt to remove #N/A

[image]

I have tried the following:

```
ws = ('C:/BAAC.xlsx')
ws.auto_filter.add_filter_column('AA:AI', '501', keep_default_na=False)
wb.save('C:/EEEA.xlsx')
```

Though it does not seem to like this.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
pd.read_excel(filename).dropna(how='any').to_excel(filename, index=False)
```

Comment: No errors but it creates a bizarre result reducing file size and data looks now like this https://ibb.co/if2rJG for filename = ('BAAC.xlsx')
pd.read_excel(filename).dropna(how='any').to_excel(filename, index=False)

Comment: @Wman, i can't open this link from my working place... `df.dropna()` removes all rows that have at least one `NaN` in any column

Comment: In my default excel I have at least 15 columns that do not have #N/A but it is displaying what I have edited in my question.

Comment: Is there a way to narrow this down to a set range?  I have tried this in other excels with less data with good results :)

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can't copy formulas to values in Python.  Also this does not work for my large workbook.  Nor can I transfer this data to a new workbook because Python does not allow this.  I believe VBA/Linux Macros are the only way which is not fun because it makes bug fixing a nightmare